# Are LinQ deferred executed queries run in order, or as a compilation of all awaiting actions

Tags: c#, linq

```
var results = from r in resultTable
              select r;

results = from results 
          where r.name == "somename"
          select r;

results = results.ToList();
```

When ToList is executed, will Linq select all results, then iterate through all results a 2nd time testing for the Where predicate?  Or will LinQ combine the Where with the first Select and iterate only once?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

Comment: What was the purpose of posting the 1st LINQ if your question is only about the 2nd?

Comment: @har07 I wanted to know if the having both, would result in double iteration of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be the first way you ask or the second depending on certain circumstances.

For example, if your query is translated into a database (and you select from `IQueryable`), then most likely both your assignments will combine into one. If the source is of type `IEnumerable`, then it will simply iterate through all the results applying **where** condition.

In neither case LinQ will iterate the collection twice. **It is designed** to iterate sequences only once.

The only way "to iterate" twice is to **execute the query** twice, which can be done, for instance, calling `ToList` or running a `foreach`.